# Spring Security: disable https for some urls

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have 3 maven modules:

1. "controller A" - spring boot web app, "/a/*" urls
2. "controller B" - another spring boot web app, "/b/*" urls
3. "common" - shared spring security configuration

And I want for "/a/*" use https and x509 and for "/b/*" use http without security (or another kind of security - jwt for example).

My current version is:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/a/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/b/**");
    }
}
```

It still runs B on https and required auth. Is it possible to configure what I want without creating separate security configuration?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using HTTP and HTTPS, you have to configure two connectors. As stated in the documentation (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl), it is not possible to do it using the config file only.

You have to configure one of the connectors (e.g. HTTPS) and add the other programmatically. This example shows how: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-multi-connectors

By the way, it is not recommended to use plain HTTP anymore.

Comment: If I run the multi connectors example and try to call http url my browser switches it to https and I get the exception `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens`.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem, please open an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues. Before doing so, check your version of Spring Boot.
However, it is not recommended to use plain HTTP anymore, unless you run Spring Boot behind a reverse proxy handling the SSL connection for you (this is the case in PaaS environment).